# Trying Retrofit(an android api library),got some issues

Tags: android, retrofit

trying out retrofit , here is my code

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)




         var rex = RetrofitClient.getClient("www.xyz.php")

         var pwq= rex?.create(login_sx.class))
```

the error is in the last line , the error seems to be a (Name Expected)**var pwq= rex?.create(login_sx.class))**

Answer (score 1):

It should be var pwq= rex?.create(login_sx::class.java))